# MS Sql extract the day value in a date

Tags: sql, sql-server

In MS SQL I am trying to get the value of day in the current date, eg: today is 25/08/2016, so this value would be the number 25. I would also like to find the value of day in an earlier date (eg: 06/06/2016 so this number would be 06). I am then looking to subtract the second value from the first and determin if the result is a positive or negative value. If it is positive it should do one thing, eg print test A and if it is a negative value it should do something else, eg print test B.

I am new to MS sql and really have no clude how to implement this in the language. Does anyone have any pointers? Much appreciated. Please see my pseudo code:

```
change = value of days in current date - value of days in previous date

if change is a positive value : print "testA"

if change is 0 or a negaitve value: print "testB"
```

I am doing this in excel 2010. I have three columns with dates in colA & colB and testA or test B should be printed in colC depending if the value is positive or negative.

Eg data:

colA: 12/02/2016, 06/06/2016, 12/02/2016
colB: 12/05/2016, 12/02/2015, 28/06/2016

Comment: Can you include some sample data?  And also tell us which version of SQL Server you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you can able to change your dates format to `MM/DD/YYYY` then below script may help you

```
DECLARE @D1 DATETIME ='08/25/2016'
DECLARE @D2 DATETIME ='06/06/2016'

IF  DATEPART(D,@D1) - DATEPART(D,@D2) > 0
  PRINT 'testA'
ELSE  
  PRINT 'testB'
```

Comment: Carefull with culture specific date literals! Your answer is only valid, if your culture implicity casts like MM/DD/YYY. Use a better format (unseparated or ISO8601) or use `CONVERT` with the appropriate culture key.

Comment: Yup Thanks @Shnugo

Answer (score 0):

Use the below script :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN  (DATEPART(dw,GETDATE())+DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()-1)) > 0 THEN  'testA' 
        WHEN (DATEPART(dw,GETDATE())+DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()-1)) =0 THEN 'testB' END Result
```

some additional info.

IF you need a particular DAY/Day Value use the below scripts

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw,'12/22/2016') --Thursday
SELECT DATEPART(dw,'12/22/2016') --5
```

IF you need a DAY of month value use the below script

```
SELECT DATEPART(dd,'12/22/2016') --22
```

Comment: Carefull with culture specific date literals! Your answer is only valid, if your culture implicity casts like MM/DD/YYY. Use a better format (unseparated or ISO8601) or use `CONVERT` with the appropriate culture key.

Comment: When I try this I get the error message 'Could not add the table '('. Do you know what is wrong? I have posted my complete code as a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39160408/merge-and-date-difference-with-sql-query-in-excel-2010